# How can I help improve Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Is it possible to help improve Stack Exchange sites for example in design, or testing functionalities, or in security or ..., or is this not possible?

If yes, can I find the source code in Github for example, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the Stack Exchange sites is closed - except for some of the libraries we use - many of those are open source:

http://stackexchange.github.io/

We are always happy to get improvements to these libraries.

In regards to design, security and testing or the sites themselves - the way to suggest improvements is through the meta sites (these are all monitored by staff - looking at bug reports, feature requests and so on).

When it comes to security vulnerabilities, we would like people to follow up with responsible disclosure - through the "[contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" page (linked at the footer of every site).

Comment: Thank you @Oded i think this can help me